# ASP.NET - Storing Article View Count in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, msmq

I am building a Wiki / Blog similar application, and I have a question about the best way to store the View Count for each of the articles.  The requirement is that I only want to store the unique number of users that viewed the article and not the total view count.  So far I have come up with 3 different ways to accomplish:

**1. SQL Server stored procedure:** the problem with this approach is that the data is stored in XML data type and it might be a bit complicated to achieve the requirement using this method. I am leaving this as a last resort.

**2. MSMQ:** this would work great, since I can process the requests serially. The only problem with this approach is that, I cannot ensure that MSMQ is installed on the host server. This one is out of the question!

**3. Using `Application.Lock()`:** I know that using this method I can lock access to the `Application` object, update some entry in the application, update the database, and then call `Application.Unlock()`. While this sounds as a functional approach, it still feels like a workaround.

Does anyone has a suggestion on what I should do to achieve the requirement?

Comment: Isn't this what web logging / analytics are for?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Google analytics?

Comment: Where are you storing the Blog Entries, in a database?  Just add a field and update accordingly.  Confused by your question.

Comment: The requirement is store in the database.  The problem is that the Count will be stored in an Xml field along with other pieces for data, and I am afraid that multiple requests would come in at the same time and overwrite each other.

Comment: [overwrite each other] will not happen

Comment: Not [overwrite each other] per say, but not storing the correct values.

Comment: It does if you use the default isolation level and locks. Writes are serialized by default so concurrency shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MsMQ and Application.Lock are def not the options to consider for something simple you want to do. (Application.Lock() is a def NO GO)

I also see no reason for XML. A stored proc does not rely on XML

Create a table
[page,userip]

on every view of the page

`insert into <table>(page,userip) values(@page,@userip)`

For the statistics just issue the a query

```
select count(*) from <table> group by userip having page=@page
```

This identifies a user on its IP, not completely failsafe as multiple users can come from the same ip.

But why not investigate google Analytics? All the info you need (and more)